# Square root of continuous function on simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

It is well that every holomorphic function on a simply connected domain which is everywhere non-zero has a holomorphic square root.

But is it true that every continuous function on a simply connected domain which is everywhere non-zero has a continuous square root?